# UK overstay from 2011 to 2014, can I apply for any other visa type now?

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying, spouses

I came to the UK on a study visa in 2010, but my college (Halifax College Harrow) got blacklisted in 2011. I then applied for new a visa. My agent committed fraud, he took £4,000 of my money but did not apply for my visa. My time was finished. Then I overstayed for 2 years in the UK. In 2014, I came back to my country. I was not banned and I bought my own flight ticket and returned to my home country.

I would like to know, am I eligible to apply again for any other type of visa?

Can I apply for a spouse visa now?

Comment: A two-year overstay makes it unlikely you'll be granted any sort of visitor visa. If you want to ask about spouse visas you should ask on [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 2):

A 2-year overstay is very big, therefore it is very unlikely you will be granted a visa.

For comparison, under rule 320(7B), overstayers are normally barred from re-entering the UK for at least one year, unless they overstayed by less than 90 days and left the UK voluntarily at their own expense.

So I imagine even if you didn’t get a ban you would most likely be refused.

A way you could get accepted is if you have significant proof of ties to your home country to show you won’t stay in the U.K. after your visa expires.

Your spouse visa could get accepted if you plan to apply for settlement and live with your partner.